# Select2 not showing results in dropdown with AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery-select2

I'm working on creating an interface for some system I am working on and I am required to write the Javascript around pre-existing PHP AJAX functions that are used elsewhere in the system (purely as the person who does our DB stuff is too busy to adapt the code to my needs).

Using Select2 I need to make a select field where the user searches for their name in the database and selects the one matching it so it can then be posted to another AJAX function later. I have done this with the following code:

```
//<select id="sltMyName" style="width: 100%;"></select>

    $("#sltMyName").select2({
      ajax: {
          type: "POST",
          url: "includes/php/report_searchPlayers.php",
          delay: 250,
          data: function (params) {
              return {
                  q: params.term // search term
              };
          },
          processResults: function (data) {
                console.log({ results: data.split(",") });
                return { results: data.split(",") };
          }
      },
      minimumInputLength: 1
    });
```

This should turn a returned string in the format of `name1,name2,name3,name...` into the required format for Select2 to display, however, it does not currently work. The dropdown just appears blank.

I've seen some questions referring to a text and id attribute, however, they are all in the context of a JSON string being returned, so I am not sure if they are required here and how to utilise them in this context. Furthermore, I cannot find any of this in the documentation.

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Data returned:
`Tommy,Jak_Tommy_Lee_Jones,Tommy_Shelby,Tommy_Balboner,TommyCZ,GA_Tommy,VA_Tommy,Tommy_Skrattar,Tommy_Knocker,Tommy_of_Elektro,Tommy_the_Destroyer,Old_Tommy,tommy_of_house_shelby,TommyDermo,TommyC,TommyCash_CZ,Tommyb69k,SA_Tommy,tommyfaster,Tommy_See,Tommy_de_Destroyer,Tommy_of_Whiteroses,TommyShelby,Templar_Intiate_Tommy,Templar_Initiate_Tommy,tommysuckspp,Tommy_the_Overweight`

Comment: Can yo provide a sample data from php file?

Comment: I've added the data returned from the PHP function in the questions. I can't really adjust the PHP function unless I know exactly what needs doing as I don't have access to that currently and would have to do it through someone else.

Comment: Which version of Select2 are you using? I'll try to help get this working.

Comment: I'm using Select2 4.0.3.

Comment: In my case, it was an issue with the z-index. Setting it to a higher value than the div I was in was sufficient.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think I've figured it out. The main issue is that the data that `Select2` wants to use needs to be an array of objects with at least a property named `id` and a property named `text`. In the `processResults` function, just create those objects & then the dropdown will populate with the data from your URL!

I've noticed that it tries to filter the data as i type, but since the url I passed in does not accept the parameters, it just returns the same data each time. Let me know if you need a more robust example.

See my fiddle at https://jsfiddle.net/yp0rp2kw/3/ for a working solution.

Comment: Yeh that seems to work, thanks. I used your solution, however used Jquery's map function to create the object, like this: `processResults: function (data) { return { results: $.map(data.split(","), function (item) { return { text: item, id: item } }) }; }`

Comment: Works fine. Thanks dude!